# SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON when reading a file using fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using Node.js v12.14.1 and I am facing an issue while parsing a JSON file containing  `\U0001f970`.

Here's the content of the file that I am trying to read and parse:

```json
{"randomKey":{"random value \U0001f970\U0001f970":1}}
```

And here's the program that I wrote to read it:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('sample.json', 'utf8'));
```

I am getting the  following error when executing the program: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 29`

When I try to parse the JSON in the REPL, it works without any issue.

```js
JSON.parse('{"randomKey":{"random value \U0001f970\U0001f970":1}}')
```

How do I read the file and parse the JSON without any issue?

Comment: In the REPL, it's `JSON.parse('{"randomKey":{"random value \\U0001f970\\U0001f970":1}}')`, which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing the JSON is invalid, thanks to [@Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64651565/5987223), I have used the following code to transform the data to valid JSON:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var json = fs.readFileSync('sample.json', 'utf8');
const sanitizedJSON = json.replace(/\\U([0-9a-f]{8})/g, (match) => String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(match.replace(/\\U/g, ''), 16)));
const data = JSON.parse(sanitizedJSON);
console.log(data);
```

This prints the desired output:

```json
{ randomKey: { 'random value ': 1 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\U` is not a valid [escape sequence in JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (and not in JavaScript string literals either). Also, a normal `\u` escape sequence is followed by 4 digits, not by 8 of them. You will need to transform your file to valid JSON - best by fixing whatever program has written it, but you can also do it on the fly:

```
const json = '{"randomKey":{"random value \\U0001f970\\U0001f970":1}}';
const data = JSON.parse(json.replace(/\\U([0-9a-f]{4})([0-9a-f]{4})/g, '\\u$1\\u$2'))
```